# Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to learn android studio. In this computer ( its not mine) android studio version is 2.2.3

When i created a new project while gradle build an error occurs.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

I have been searching for this error for one day. I haven't found the same topic anywhere so i have to open this thread.Thanks for all answers from now.

this is build.gradle(project:myapplication2)

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
     jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
       url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is build.gradle(module:app)

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alicetin.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
   buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


 dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
```

appcompat-v7 version 28 is still **alpha**

Comment: As soon as I tried as you suggested, I got this instead -- `Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler`

Comment: @NarendraJi try `complie` instead, because `implementation` is used in newer versions of Gradle

Answer (score 9):

**Try**

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`

**instead of**

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`

I faced the same issue and It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
```

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exact same problem although my build.gradle(app) file has already been updated with the latest production version of SDK, tools and libraries.

The only thing left to check is the gradle version and in fact there was a warning saying that a newer gradle version is available. Please refer to image below.

[more than one library with 'android.support.graphics.drawable'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdwAK.png)

Once I uprev the gradle version, the error got resolved.

**So please upgrade your gradle version from 2.2.3 to a newer version.**

Answer (score 1):

"com.android.support:appcompat-v7" depends on "support-vector-drawable"
and 
"com.android.support:design" depends on "animated-vector-drawable"

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
        exclude module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
}
```

Sush as:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // ...
    configurations.all {
        exclude module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    }
}
```